# RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression to force length in 10 or 12 symbols

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, validation

`RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression="\d{10}"` means only digits - 10 max.

`RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression="\d{10,12}"` means only digits - 10, 11 or 12.

How to force strictly 10 or 12 symbols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^\d{10}$|^\d{12}$`

The two `^$` are important if you want an exact 10 or 12 digits.

By the way, If you are making a lot of regexp this website is great : http://rubular.com/

Have fun

Comment: @Niklaos: Thanks! It's what I was exactly searching for. I tried the same expression as Dillie-O and Mark Byers wrote but got no success.

Comment: or the regulator, if you prefer and offline variant: http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/

Answer (score 7):

One way is:

```
"\d{10}(\d{2})?"
```

Or you could be more explicit, at the cost of a little performance:

```
"^(\d{10}|\d{12})$"
```

The reason for the anchors in the second expression is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.validationexpression.aspx):

> If you experience problems with pattern-matching constructs, try wrapping the expression with "^(" and ")$". For example, "a|ab" becomes "^(a|ab)$".

---

**Update**

I was interested in why `\d{10}|\d{12}` did not work correctly, and decided to dip into the source code for the validator to see why this fails.

The `RegularExpressionValidator` validates both server-side and client-side using the same regular expression and in the case of `\d{10}|\d{12}` it fails on the client-side for length 12, but works for length 10. The source-code reveals how the match is made:

```
var rx = new RegExp(val.validationexpression);
var matches = rx.exec(value);
return (matches != null && value == matches[0]);
```

Note that this regular expression is `A|B` but if A matches, B is never even checked - the regular expression is not "greedy" over the pipe operation - it takes the first match it finds. So the result of matching this regular expression is that the ten digit match succeeds even if you give a 12 digit input. But then the test `value == matches[0]` fails because the match is not the full string.

Swapping the order of the terms, i.e. writing `\d{12}|\d{10}`, *does* work because the longer match is tested first, and the shorter match is only tested if the long match fails.

Lesson learned: it is a good idea to explicitly use anchors when using the pipe in `RegularExpressionValidator` to avoid having to worry about the order of the terms.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Thank you very much! Very interesting. Indeed I tried the same expression as you recommended before posted a question on SO and it didn't work. And now it's absolutely clear for me why.

Comment: @abatischev: Glad it helped. I also learned something from investigating this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the regular expression "pipe"

```
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = "\d{10}|\d{12}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{10}(?:\d{2}){0,1}
```

should match 10 digits or 10+2 digits. the `(?:.....)` part is a non capturing group