# Simple C# regex question

Tags: c#, regex

**Question**: What's the simplest way how to test if given `Regex` matches whole string ?

**An example:**
E.g. given `Regex re = new Regex(".");` I want to test if given input string has only one character using this Regex `re`. How do I do that ?

**In other words**: I'm looking for method of class `Regex` that works similar to method `matches()` in class `Matcher` in Java ("Attempts to match the **entire region** against the pattern.").

***Edit:*** This question is not about getting length of some `string`. The question is how to match **whole** strings with regular exprestions. The example used here is only for demonstration purposes (normally everybody would check the `Length` property to recognise one character strings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are allowed to change the regular expression you should surround it by `^( ... )$`. You can do this at runtime as follows:

```
string newRe = new Regex("^(" + re.ToString() + ")$");
```

The parentheses here are necessary to prevent creating a regular expression like `^a|ab$` which will **not** do what you want. This regular expression matches any string starting with `a` or any string ending in `ab`.

---

If you don't want to change the regular expression you can check `Match.Value.Length == input.Length`. This is the method that is used in ASP.NET regular expression validators. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337176/regularexpressionvalidator-validationexpression-to-force-length-in-10-or-12-symbo/2337189#2337189) for a fuller explanation.

Note this method can cause some curious issues that you should be aware of. The regular expression "a|ab" will match the string 'ab' but the value of the match will only be "a". So even though this regular expression could have matched the whole string, it did not. There is a warning about this in the documentation.

Comment: This answer is the most complex one, I consider question fully answered by this one.

Answer (score 4):

use an anchored pattern

```
Regex re = new Regex("^.$");
```

for testing string length i'd check the `.Length` property though (`str.Length == 1`) …

Comment: +1 for the obvious "check string length" approach. Unless you want to match for a certain character according to a more complex rule, that's the best approach by far.

Comment: A slight difference is that `.` doesn't match `"\n"` unless you specify `RegexOptions.Singleline`. Not too important, really `:P`

Comment: The obvious check is fine but I suspect though that it was just an example to clarify the question... not actually what he wants to do.

Comment: Mark Byers is right of cause. Please read the "Edit" paragraph I added right now. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
"b".Length == 1
```

is a much better candidate than

```
Regex.IsMatch("b", "^.$")
```

Answer (score 3):

You add "start-of-string" and "end-of-string" anchors

```
^.$
```